# Highstock flags onSeries with addSeries

Tags: highcharts

The chart series add looks like:

```
series: seriesOptions
```

seriesOptions is just a normal object list with series - anyway it works fine at all.
Now I would like to add some flags to a specific series, which is possible with onSeries.

```
chart.addSeries({
        type : 'flags',
        data: events,
        name: 'events',
        id: 'events',
        color : '#5F86B3',
        fillColor : '#5F86B3',
        onSeries : 'series1',
        width : 30,
        y : -100,
        shape : 'circlepin',
        style : {// text style
            color : 'white'
        },
        states : {
            hover : {
                fillColor : '#395C84'
            }
        }
    });
```

But they are still appearing on the bottom of the chart (which is the default setting).
For me it looks like the flags cant find the id of the series to appear - Isnt it possible to use addSeries() for flags?

**Edit:** here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/HWm4J/3/

seriesOptions console.log from the firebug:

```
[Object { id="series1", name="series1", data=[3574], more...}, Object { id="series2", name="series1", data=[412], more...}, Object { id="series3", name="series3", data=[497], more...}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you jsFiddle doesn't work and when I tried to reproduce issue on Highcharts example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Crk7/1/ it works perfectly fine.

I can only guess that id you set is wrong one, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Crk7/2/

Working example for adding series:

```
    $("#b").click(function () {
        Highcharts.charts[0].addSeries({
            type : 'flags',
            name: 'events',
            id: 'events',
            color: '#5F86B3',
            fillColor: '#5F86B3',
            onSeries: 'series1',
            width: 30,
            y: -100,
            shape: 'circlepin',
            style: { // text style
                color: 'white'
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    fillColor: '#395C84'
                }
            },
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 14),
                title: 'On series'
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title: 'On series'
            }],
        });

    });
```

If you want more help, recreate issue on jsFiddle, or at least post your full chart configuration.

Comment: well it still worked for me on a chart with one series. I guess the problem is at the line 109 in my jsFiddle. There could be some problems with ids when I am adding multiple series at the same time. Tested it once again to alert the series ids - the ids are available but I cant assign to them somehow...

Comment: No, there is no problem in #109 line - there is simple assignment. Could you do one of above? I mean jsFiddle with issue, or chart/series config? Similar to what you have posted from firebug, but full one to use in jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Okay, and what is wrong on this chart? You have connected series1 with flags. series1 is the blue one on top, and there is no data for that series, where you display flags :) That's why they are displayed like on axis. Anyway, for future reference: add series at the same time, not after chart is loading, see: http://jsfiddle.net/HWm4J/4/

Comment: yes I see, but I am not showing the whole data in the jsfiddle example - on my server it didnt works and I dont know why. (the series is available at the datetime of the event) unbelievable

Answer (score 0):

Is your `'series1'` valid? That is the series your code states to add the flags to. If this series has not been made yet or is not correctly identified then it will draw the flags in the default location. Did you try redrawing the chart upon [adding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.addSeries%28%29) this series?

Comment: yes, the series should be valid. I did a console.log(seriesOptions) and it returned all series with ids. Tryed to redraw aswell but it didnt works for me.

Comment: I cannot even get your fiddle to draw the chart. The `console.log(seriesOptions);` does not write anything. JSHint is throwing up some warnings as well.

Comment: Based on the flow of your jsFiddle you never actually parse the data and you never actually add `series1` to the chart.

Comment: as u can see, I have 3 params (data is webservice based) it wont works anyway, I just posted it to show you my code. everything works fine, the series are displayed, but the flags wont be onSeries

Comment: Okay, so, If the code you sent to jsFiddle is valid on your end you still see that you never actually set the `series1` to the chart. I see you making the series, adding data to the series, but it is never handed off to the chart.

Comment: Buddy, I understood what u want but u didnt understand the code I posted. The series with the id 'series1' is in the seriesOptions which I am adding in line 109...

Comment: Line 109 is the issue - you are probably not assigning it before you are adding the flag series. Why not generate the seriesOptions, add to chart, then, after chart is loaded add the flags?